# using es6 modules: Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I want to use es6 modules and I installed babel plugin (es2015-modules-amd) for them. But what I write in the module is not imported to the main file, console errors: " Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined" at the first attempt to import anything. 
Same thing has happened when I tried to use common.js with those require statements, console just has pointed, the error and that require is not defined too.
What is it?

Comment: What AMD module loader are you using? It should provide the `define` function.

Comment: I installed es2015-modules-amd
es2015-modules-commonjs for that. Is it what you mean?

Comment: or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Just googled browserify. Should I use this one? Or what is the best module loader in your opinion?

Comment: No, I mean something like requirejs or systemjs. Browserify just bundles commonjs modules into one huge script, IIRC.

Comment: no I didn't use any of these, so it's prob the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get a module bundler, after I used it, everything went fine

Answer (score 0):

i had to install

```
npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd
```

and use `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method solved my problem when it came up "define is not defined" error from babel:

```
npm install --save-dev browserify 
browserify input.js > output.js
```

Although it's `browserify` easily solved the problem.