# How to import JS in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I downloaded a template and put all the CSS in a folder and imported it into the **App.js** file, and now I want to import the JavaScript files, but it gives an error, I even used **/ * global jQuery * /** and put it in the **index.js** file. but it still gives an error

Is it possible to import JS file at all? If so, thank you for your reply

Error image:[Error Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF0Ks.png)

**UPDATE**

in **App.js**

```html
import './App.css';
import './dist/css/adminlte.min.css';
import './dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css';
import './dist/css/custom-style.css';
import './plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './dist/js/adminlte.js';
```

Comment: if it is normal js or jquery files, link it in index.html in public as we do in normal html

Comment: Can you give more information about your code so that others can locate the question fastly

Comment: @screwspike there you go i Upadted the question

Comment: add css and js files in script tags. You can either add them to your index.html (`<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/js/adminlte.js">`) or create a wrapper react component which loads the script and provides a way to interact with the module it loads.

Comment: @Gandzal i did that too ....,it does not work

Comment: I think you should check your webpack and babel config, the  `define is not defined` error seems like the js modules error, your can get some idea from this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531091/using-es6-modules-uncaught-referenceerror-define-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally just import your JS Files like any other React Component.

JS: `export function myfunc(){return "Your JS stuff here")`

React: `import {myfunc} from "wherever"`